# Ignore S00107 with @JsonCreator annotated constructor

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using SQ 6.0 and I have some POJOs which are (de)serialized by Spring/Jackson. For immutability reasons all members are passed to the constructor, so SQ complains with "Constructor has X parameters, which is greater than 7 authorized".

Since the constructor is annotated with `@JsonCreator` the number of arguments should imho be ignored, is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case would indeed make sense to have a way to exclude those constructors the same way constructors with @RequestMapping annotation are automatically excluded : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-2415. The short answer is no, there is no way. I'm going to open a thread on the SonarQube mailing list on this subject to see what we could do at mid-term.